# get write, read, execute permission of a folder to a user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chown

In an ubuntu server 18.04, I have 2 users: userA and userB. There is a folder

```
/home/userA/data
```

I am going to get read, write, execute access of `data` to userB.

unfortunately the command

```
chown userB /home/userA/data
```

does not work.

Comment: Are you wanting both userA AND userB to have RWX on /home/userA/data? Or to change ownership of the location to ONLY userB? Are you sure chown is what you want to use, and othwerwise not to create a group consisting of userA and userB, and then grant that group ownership+rwx perms to /home/userA/data? Which system user are you executing chown as?

Comment: what does the command return? the command is correct, do you (the user running the command) have permissions over `/home/userA/data`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setfacl`

https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-configure-access-control-lists-acls-setfacl-getfacl-linux/#

```
setfacl -m u:userB:rwx /home/userA/data
setfacl -m u:userB:x   /home/userA
setfacl -m u:userB:x   /home
```